# What could be happen with ruby and vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-provision

I just configured a new WordPress project and when I do `vagrant up`, I'm getting this error:

```
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:377:in `parse': (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 54 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:377:in `parse_stream'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:325:in `parse'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:252:in `load'
    from /home/fabio/Vagrant/pessoasaltas.com/Vagrantfile:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:126:in `block (2 levels) in load'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:119:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:119:in `block in load'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:116:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:116:in `load'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:29:in `initialize'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:792:in `new'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:792:in `vagrantfile'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:973:in `process_configured_plugins'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:178:in `initialize'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/bin/vagrant:145:in `new'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/bin/vagrant:145:in `<main>'
```

I'm on Linux Mint 19.3 with Vagrant 2.2.6;
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

Anyone can help me?

Comment: I'm sorry for the title, but none of the suggested answers were appropriate for my question.

Comment: At the very least, you need to edit your question and add your Vagrantfile. At first glance, there is a yaml file loaded somewhere that is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a line pointing to your vagrantfile:

```
from /home/fabio/Vagrant/pessoasaltas.com/Vagrantfile:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

And you can also run vagrant in debug mode to get more information:

```
vagrant up --debug
```